# high stock area chart not working own our json

Tags: highcharts

I am using high chart stock and it is using json to plot graph.
I have changed high stock json file with my own local file placed on local server, but it's not working and giving results of high char json file even i have changed json file data as well.
problem is chart is not ploting as per my local file, it's produce results of highchart json file which I have replaced with my local file.
Please find the code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Highstock Example</title>

        <style type="text/css">

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="highstock.js"></script>
<script src="exporting.js"></script>
<script src="export-data.js"></script>



<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>


        <script type="text/javascript">
<!-- below get json file is the local file that contain chart data --> 


            $.getJSON('http://localhost:2904/WebSite1/aapl-c.json', function (data) {

    // Create the chart
    Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1
        },

        title: {
            text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'AAPL Stock Price',
            data: data,
            type: 'area',
            threshold: null,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            },
            fillColor: {
                linearGradient: {
                    x1: 0,
                    y1: 0,
                    x2: 0,
                    y2: 1
                },
                stops: [
                    [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                    [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                ]
            }
        }]
    });
});

        </script>
    </body>
</html>


JSON FIle : 
[

[1147651200000,1100.79],
[1147737600000,64.98],
[1147824000000,65.26],

[1147651200000,1167.79],
[1147737600000,64.98],
[1147824000000,65.26],

[1147651200000,1167.79],
[1147737600000,64.98],
[1147824000000,65.26],

[1147651200000,1167.79],
[1147737600000,64.98],
[1147824000000,65.26],

[1147651200000,1167.79],
[1147737600000,64.98],
[1147824000000,65.26],

[1147651200000,1167.79],
[1147737600000,64.98],
[1147824000000,65.26],
]
```

Comment: I don't quite understand. So the problem is that `data` argument doesn't contain the data from `http://localhost:2904/WebSite1/aapl-c.json` file?